# Prove that $\Sigma_{i=0}^{n-1} (\Sigma_{j=i+1}^n(j(^nC_i) + i(^nC_j))) = n^22^{n-1}$

Tags: summation, binomial-theorem, combinatorial-proofs

I have tried setting
$$P=\Sigma_{i=0}^{n-1} (\Sigma_{j=i+1}^n(j(^nC_i) + i(^nC_j))$$
then
$$P=\Sigma_{i=0}^{n-1} (\Sigma_{j=i+1}^n((n-j)(^nC_i) + (n-i)(^nC_j))$$
now adding them both
$$2P=\Sigma_{i=0}^{n-1} (\Sigma_{j=i+1}^n(n((^nC_i)+(^nC_j))))$$
I think that we have to go ahead from here but I'm not able to think of anything else. Am I even on the right path? Please Help. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by $^nC_i$?

Comment: @SergeyZaitsev It means choose(n, i)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}}&\color{blue}{\sum_{j=i+1}^n\left(j\binom{n}{i}+i\binom{n}{j}\right)}\\
> &=\sum_{0\leq i<j\leq n}\left(j\binom{n}{i}+i\binom{n}{j}\right)\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{0\leq i\ne j\leq n}i\binom{n}{j}\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{0\leq i,j\leq n}i\binom{n}{j}-\sum_{0\leq i=j\leq n}i\binom{n}{j}\\
> &=\left(\sum_{i=0}^ni\right)\left(\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}{j}\right)-\sum_{i=0}^ni\binom{n}{i}\tag{3}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)2^n-n\sum_{i=1}^n\binom{n-1}{i-1}\tag{4}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)2^n-n\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{i}\tag{5}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)2^n-n2^{n-1}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=n^22^{n-1}}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we write the index region somewhat more conveniently to better see what's going on.
- in (2) we use the symmetry of the index region and the summands.
- In (3) we can write the sums separating the indices $i$ and $j$.
- In (4) we simplify using closed forms and apply the binomial identity $\binom{p}{q}=\frac{p}{q}\binom{p-1}{q-1}$.
- In (5) we shift the index to start with $i=0$ and use again a closed form expression as in (4).

Comment: thanks so much! Writing the indexes like that made it a lot more easier to understand what step I can take next.

Comment: @SolitarySolus: You're welcome! Good to see the answer is helpful. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going ahead and assume $^nC_i=\binom{n}{i}$ and so
$$2P=n\sum_{i=0}^n \sum_{j=i+1}^n \left( \binom{n}{i} + \binom{n}{j} \right) = n\sum_{i=0}^n (n-i)\binom{n}{i} + n\sum_{j=0}^n\sum_{i=0}^{j-1} \binom{n}{j}
=n^2\sum_{i=0}^{n} \binom{n}{i}=n^2 2^n$$

Comment: okay, I understand the first part of the second step. But how did you change the limits of the sum like that? Can you please explain?

Comment: I forgot the name of it, maybe someone can add. Imagine points in the 2d-plane above the 1-to-1 line. You are summing over the lattice from $i=0$ to $n$ and from $j=i+1$ to $n$. This can also be done by first summing over $j$ from $1$ to $n$ and then for $i$ from $0$ to $j-1$.